# google.maps.overlayview API equivalent in Leaflet

Tags: google-maps, leaflet

I am using google.maps.overlayview in google maps API for displaying views that render HTML and tied to a geolocation. Code example is below

```
/* MAP CONFRIM FOR GOOGLE MAPS CODE START */
function MapConfirm(opt_options, offset) {
    // Initializationf
    this.setValues(opt_options);
    this.offset = offset;

    // Here go the MapConfirm styles
    this.textBlock = document.createElement("div");
    this.container = document.createElement("div");
    //$(this.container).addClass("ui-widget").addClass("ui-dialog").addClass("ui-widget-content").addClass("ui-corner-all");
    $(this.textBlock).addClass("ui-widget").addClass("marker-confirm");
    $(this.container).addClass("marker-confirm-container");

    this.okButton = document.createElement("div");
    this.cancelButton = document.createElement("div");
    $(this.okButton).html("Tamam").addClass("marker-button").button();
    $(this.cancelButton).html("Vazgeç").addClass("marker-button").button();
    this.container.appendChild(this.textBlock);
    this.container.appendChild(this.cancelButton);
    this.container.appendChild(this.okButton);
};

MapConfirm.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;

MapConfirm.prototype.onAdd = function () {
    var pane = this.getPanes().overlayImage;
    pane.appendChild(this.container);

    // Ensures the MapConfirm is redrawn if the text or position is changed.
    var me = this;
    this.listeners_ = [
          google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'position_changed',
               function () { me.draw(); }),
          google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'text_changed',
               function () { me.draw(); }),
          google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'zindex_changed',
               function () { me.draw(); })
     ];
};

// Implement onRemove
MapConfirm.prototype.onRemove = function () {
    this.container.parentNode.removeChild(this.container);

    // MapConfirm is removed from the map, stop updating its position/text.
    for (var i = 0, I = this.listeners_.length; i < I; ++i) {
        google.maps.event.removeListener(this.listeners_[i]);
    }
};

// Implement draw
MapConfirm.prototype.draw = function () {
    var projection = this.getProjection();
    var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));
    this.container.style.left = (position.x + this.offset.x) + 'px';
    this.container.style.top = (position.y + this.offset.y) + 'px';
    this.container.style.display = 'block';
    this.container.style.zIndex = this.get('zIndex'); //ALLOW MapConfirm TO OVERLAY MARKER
    $(this.textBlock).html(this.get('text').toString());
};

/* MAP CONFRIM FOR GOOGLE MAPS CODE END */
```

I want to implement a similar class with leaflet. is it possible what leaflet feature should i use?

For instance i would like to display a control like this, and it'll be dragged with marker.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It was just a single down vote, not from me, but your question does look to be very broad. Consider showing your own attempt to solve it and showing that in your question as well as telling how it's not working. Also consider deleting your comment above as it is "down-vote bait".

Comment: @Numenor I don't get what you want to achieve. Something like an `L.Popup`??

Comment: @IvanSanchez yes but i would like to display any html and i want to fully customize its look and feel. and i would like to bind this view to anything and one marker might have multiple views which will be shown on different cases. You can say that i would like to have a L.Control but bind its position to a marker(actually a bit with an offset) instead of map corners/middle etc.

Comment: Adding a screenshot or sketch of what it should look like would probably help.

Comment: @Numenor Have you actually tried to use a `L.Popup`??

Comment: @ghybs i have attached a screenshot of what i have done with google maps api, i want to do the same with leaflet.

Comment: @IvanSanchez i did try L:Popup but it looks like a balloon.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @IvanSanchez, you could achieve your objective by using an [`L.popup`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup) and restyling it, in order to get rid of the default appearance and display only your custom HTML content.

Another easy solution (might be closer to your objective, even though you did not describe it explicitly) would be to use a [`L.divIcon`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divicon) as [`icon`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-icon) option of a `L.marker`. With this solution, you have more freedom to supply your custom HTML, and you can easily have a draggable marker. However, the entire "icon" is draggable, which may not be exactly the UI you are trying to get (but again, you have not say anything about it in your question).

A more complex solution, but still very manageable, would be to use again a draggable marker, and provide your custom HTML to a [`L.tooltip`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tooltip). Like the popup, you would need to restyle it to remove the default Tooltip appearance. The advantage is that the Tooltip does not activate the marker (dragging through the Tooltip pans the map, instead of dragging the marker), and you get the automatic positioning (left or right of the marker, depending on the position of the latter in the viewport).

```js
var map = L.map("map").setView([48.85, 2.35], 12);

var html = '<div class="tooltipText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor.</div>' +
  '<div class="tooltipButtons"><button>Button A</button><button>Button B</button></div>';

L.marker([48.835, 2.3], {
  draggable: true
}).addTo(map).bindTooltip(html, {
  permanent: true,
  className: 'customTooltip',
  opacity: 1,
  offset: [0, -60]
});

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<style>
  .customTooltip {
    /* Counter leaflet-tooltip styles */
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 0;
    pointer-events: inherit;
    box-shadow: none;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 250px;
  }
  
  .customTooltip:before {
    /* Counter leaflet-tooltip styles */
    content: none !important;
  }
  
  .tooltipText,
  .tooltipButtons button {
    background-color: rgba(60, 60, 60, .9);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .tooltipText {
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  .tooltipButtons button {
    border: none;
    margin-left: .5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: .2em .5em;
  }
  
  .tooltipButtons button:hover {
    background-color: darkblue;
  }
  
  .tooltipButtons {
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: .5em;
  }
</style>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```